# Photosphere plugin, cursor stuck on "grabbed" and text won't select

Tags: javascript, html, css, photosphere

I'm working on a new version of my business site at http://bigriverwebdesign.com.  I'm trying to implement a Photosphere background (http://photo-sphere-viewer.js.org/).  I've contacted the plugin author, but he's been unresponsive and I'd like to see if anyone on StackOverflow has an insight.

I almost have things working the way I want them, but are two hangups I can't figure out.

1) The cursor displays as a grabbed hand.  I would like to change it to all-scroll.  I don't think this has to do with my implementation because it is the same way on the plugin site.  I am unable to change the cursor with CSS and I'm not sure that it is being set with CSS in the first place.  Does anyone know why the browser displays things this way and how I might go about overriding it?

2) I can't select text to copy and paste from pages like http://www.bigriverwebdesign.com/services. If I remove the photosphere, I'm able to select text just fine.  I'm having trouble finding any information on this.

thank you!